# How to bind a collection of nested dictionaries to a TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, data-binding, treeview

I have a collection of nested Dictionary objects. Each dictionary shows the following structure:

```
[Title]  -> String
[Childs] -> Dictionary<string, object>
       |
       |
       [Title]  -> String
       [Childs] -> Dictionary<string, object>
              |
              |
             ....
```

and so on, last element of each 'path' consisting only of the [Title] entry (no Childs).

With the Xaml below, the complete collection with each and every node get shown, but i get an exception when expanding a node containing leafs with no childrens.

It's like, how can i say it, like i'm looking one level ahead while binding the current level. But my treeview shows the whole collection from first to last element. What's wrong?

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding [Childs]}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Width="12" Height="14" Source="{StaticResource items_ico}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                <Label Content="{Binding [Name]}" ToolTip="{Binding [Name]}" ToolTipService.Placement="Top"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Edit: Sorry. The first post was incomplete (slipped onto return key)

Comment: If it is WPF or ASP please tag it so! Also please ask your question a lot more clearly..

Comment: What kind of keys do your dictionaries have?  What kind of values, besides other dictionaries?  Two way binding or one way?

Comment: Ok, what about this: How would you bind a treeview to a list of nested dictionary<string, object> where object = dictionary<string,object>?

Comment: No answers. Should i assume it's not advisable to bind to a dictionary? Or there is a contest on who finds out first?

Comment: You know it, but you won't tell me, isn't it?

Comment: 'Nested Dictionaries!!'. Scary, uh?

Comment: You know, 'who cares' too is an (well, almost) acceptable answer.